# I have UIView extensions, In this extension I have one method setDarkModeColor how to call every time when init view

Tags: ios, swift, ios13

I have one function in extension which is change my view background colour in dark mode and light mode , i need to this method call every time when init view.

**Here my code like this :**

```
extension UIView{
        func setDarkModeColor()  {
            if #available(iOS 12.0, *) {
                if self.traitCollection.userInterfaceStyle == .light{
                    if self.backgroundColor == UIColor.black{
                        self.backgroundColor = .white
                    }
                }else{
                    if self.backgroundColor == UIColor.white{
                        self.backgroundColor = .black
                    }
                }
            } else {
                // Fallback on earlier versions
            }
        } 
    }
```

Comment: You should add specific colors for each background, on each view, like Apple suggests (one for dark mode, one for light mode): https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/supporting_dark_mode_in_your_interface/ . The OS will make the changes automatically, when you change between modes.

Comment: Yes we can use this approach but in exciting app we can follow this process then lengthy process. so i think if we use extension then this approach better.

Comment: You can also create a subclass of UIView and override the init statements to make sure this method is called.

Comment: @Leo Yes we can do it, but it change all swift files, storyboard and Xib. so it might be long process. so we can find optimal solutions use extension.

Answer (score 1):

You should not be changing the default behavior of a standard UIView or any class that you have not written or you do not own. At least, extensions are not the place to do so. Though possible, it is extremely bad and highly discouraged practice to override existing functions inside an extension.

Instead, you should override UIView():

```
class MyView: UIView {
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        setDarkModeColor()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        setDarkModeColor()
    }

    func setDarkModeColor()  {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

about overriding in extension: [apple official docs](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Extensions.html)

```
    NOTE

Extensions can add new functionality to a type, but they cannot override existing functionality.
```

You should find another way :(

Answer (score 0):

You can't. You cannot use an *extension* to cause a method to be called. You can *inject* this method using an extension, but *you* would have to call it yourself, explicitly, in every UIView.

Anyway, you don't need this approach. If you want to give a UIView a background color that responds to dark/light mode, then *give* it a background color that responds to dark/light mode. In iOS 13, colors have that ability; a color configured in this way will respond to dark/light mode *automatically*. You can create such a color as a named color in the asset catalog, or you can construct it in code by calling `init(dynamicProvider:)`. For example:

```
let myCoolColor = UIColor { tc in
    switch tc.userInterfaceStyle {
    case .dark:
        return UIColor(red: 0.3, green: 0.4, blue: 0.4, alpha: 1)
    default:
        return UIColor(red: 0, green: 0.1, blue: 0.1, alpha: 1)
    }
}
```

If you assign `myCoolColor` as a view's background color, the color will change *automatically* depending on the user's mode.